# Display a resultset where each cell is based on different condition using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table from which I query data to display resultset using stored procedure. I also have a value to be given in the where condition  that keeps changing for each and every cell and that parameter is not available in the table from which I have to query. As of now, I have hardcoded the for that particular parameter. My resultset should consist of 7 rows and 16 columns. Is there any optimistic way instead of hardcoding it ? Any help is appreciated.

Here is the temp table I ve hardcoded:

```
 create table #temp_financials(iden_val int identity(1,1) ,
     categ varchar(100),Retail_RDR varchar(100),Avg_Price_RDR varchar(100), 
             GPVR_RDR   varchar(100),
            L_RDR varchar(100),
       L_Avg_Price varchar(100),L_GPVL varchar(100),
    C_RDR varchar(100),C_Avg_Price varchar(100),C_GPVR varchar(100),
     C_Rgn_GPVR varchar(100),C_Nat_GPVR varchar(100),
       C_Lease_Penet varchar(100),C_Rgn_Penet varchar(100))

    insert into #temp_financials(categ,Retail_RDR ,Avg_Price_RDR , GPVR_RDR ,
      L_RDR ,L_Avg_Price ,L_GPVL ,
        C_RDR ,C_Avg_Price ,C_GPVR ,C_Rgn_GPVR ,C_Nat_GPVR ,
        C_Lease_Penet ,C_Rgn_Penet ) 
                 values('Ttl  Sum',             
         'B9720','B9996','B9776','B9722','B9997','B9791','B9733','B10003','B9806','B9806                 ','B9806','B9885','B9885'  )
         insert into #temp_financials(categ,Retail_RDR ,Avg_Price_RDR , GPVR_RDR ,
     L_RDR ,L_Avg_Price ,L_GPVL ,
          C_RDR ,C_Avg_Price ,C_GPVR ,C_Rgn_GPVR ,C_Nat_GPVR ,
         C_Lease_Penet ,C_Rgn_Penet ) 
                  values        ('B9870','B9773','4042A','B9998','B9788',
            'B9872','B2090','B9803','B9803','B9803','B10004','B10004')
```

Here is the table with which I ve to join:

```
     while(@loop_var<=@count_var)
        begin

       select                  t.categ,Retail_RDR=w1.CMValue,Avg_Price_RDR=w2.CMValue,
        GPVR_RDR=w3.CMValue,L_RDR=w4.CMValue,
    from westernunion  w1 join #temp_financials t on     
    w1.acct_no=t.retail_RDR left  outer join 
        westernunion  w2 on   w2.acct_no=t.avg_price_rdr 
        left outer join westernunion  w3 on  w3.acct_no=t.GPVR_RDR   
        left outer join westernunion w4 on w4.acct_no=t.L_RDR 
        where        t.iden_val=@loop_var
             set @loop_var=@loop_var+1
          end
```

Comment: sorry the question isn't clear enough...do you want your result set to be exactly 7 rows and 16 columns regardless of the parameter you pass?

Comment: ya the resultset should have 7 rows and 16 columns, and there is one paramter that keeps varying for each cell..

Comment: you can always use "select top 7 <column list> from <table>"..and use dynamic sql to pass the parameter.

Comment: okay.. thanks... but how do I store the values in the form of a matrix table which will contain different values for each cell because I wanna join my table  with the matrix table and display the 7 rows and 16 columns..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL query:

```
Declare @vQuery nvarchar(max),
        @vWhereClasue varchar(500)

SET @vQuery = 'Select top 7 col1,col2 ....col16 from ... where ' + @vWhereClasue
exec sp_executesql @vQuery
```

Comment: Thanks.. but I've got only one table and the thing is I need to display results based on a join condition for a column and I don't have the second table in my db. So I need to hardcode a table in my sp with nearly 78 values, which is what I wanna avoid.

Comment: can you explain more like what your table structure or it will be better if you give any sample example of your query.